# Can not resolve reference: System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

Tags: c#, build, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Solution in Visual Studio. But everytime I try to compile the iOS project I got the following error message:

> Can not resolve reference: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/QSMobil.iOS/3b412dbb137e0cd8903009453a101181/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll ProjectName.iOS C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets   696

I read a lot of updating my build server... But both the Mac (Xamarin Studio) and the Windows PC (VS) are up to date.

By the way it's possible to build the Android version of the app.

Maybe someone could help me?

EDIT:

I solved the problem by removing System.Data from the Assemblys.

Comment: Do you actually the reference? Else, go into you csproj file with a text editor and see if there is a reference, if you are not using it, remove it.

Comment: I can't find the Wrapper.dll in the csproj file.

Comment: Xamarin.iOS [does not support System.Enterprise](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/#Supported_Assemblies), but it [does support System.Data](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/system.data/). If you are not trying to use any of the [missing functionality](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/system.data/#Missing_Functionality) and are seeing this error, can you include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in case this is a bug? Thanks!

Comment: @jimmgarr We are tried to open a `SqlConnection` that was the problem. Stupid mistake...